# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when using valueChanges.subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular 5 with Reactive forms and need to make use of the valueChanges in order to disable required validation dynamically

component class:

```
export class UserEditor implements OnInit {

    public userForm: FormGroup;
    userName: FormControl;
    firstName: FormControl;
    lastName: FormControl;
    email: FormControl;
    loginTypeId: FormControl;
    password: FormControl;
    confirmPassword: FormControl;
...

ngOnInit() {
    this.createFormControls();
    this.createForm();
    this.userForm.get('loginTypeId').valueChanges.subscribe(

            (loginTypeId: string) => {
                console.log("log this!");
                if (loginTypeId === "1") {
                    console.log("disable validators");
                    Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$')]);
                    this.userForm.get('password').setValidators([]);
                    this.userForm.get('confirmPassword').setValidators([]);

                } else if (loginTypeId === '2') {
                    console.log("enable validators");
                    this.userForm.get('password').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]);
                    this.userForm.get('confirmPassword').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]);

                }

                this.userForm.get('loginTypeId').updateValueAndValidity();

            }

        )
}
createFormControls() {
    this.userName = new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(4)
    ]);
    this.firstName = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.lastName = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.email = new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern("[^ @]*@[^ @]*")
    ]);
    this.password = new FormControl('', [
       Validators.required,
       Validators.minLength(8)
    ]);
    this.confirmPassword = new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8)
    ]);

}

createForm() {
 this.userForm = new FormGroup({
      userName: this.userName,
      name: new FormGroup({
        firstName: this.firstName,
        lastName: this.lastName,
      }),
      email: this.email,
      loginTypeId: this.loginTypeId,
      password: this.password,
      confirmPassword: this.confirmPassword
    });
}
```

However when I run it I get a browser javascript error

```
UserEditor.html:82 ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at SafeSubscriber.tryCatcher (tryCatch.js:9)
    at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscription.js.Subscription.unsubscribe (Subscription.js:68)
    at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.unsubscribe (Subscriber.js:124)
    at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:242)
    at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:186)
    at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:127)
    at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:91)
    at EventEmitter.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subject.js.Subject.next (Subject.js:56)
    at EventEmitter.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit (core.js:4319)
    at FormControl.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/esm5/forms.js.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:3377)
```

"log this!" is loggedcalled repeatedly like it is called recursively which is why their is a stack error

If I remove the valueChanges.subscribe the code work apart from removing the validation conditionally.

Why is it calling valueChanges.subscribe  recursively?

Comment: Isn't it because you call `updateValueAndValidity()` at the end of the event handler?

Comment: I agree with ConnorsFan, `updateValueAndValidity()` is probably causing valueChanges to fire again, causing an infinite loop

Comment: @ConnorsFan thats the reason for the recursion. I shouldn't update the same field I am monitoring for change. Code was meant to be 'this.userForm.get('loginTypeId').'. You can put it in an answer

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is that you modify the value of the field inside of the `valueChanges` event handler for that same field, causing the event to be triggered again:

```
this.userForm.get('loginTypeId').valueChanges.subscribe(
  (loginTypeId: string) => {
    ...
    this.userForm.get('loginTypeId').updateValueAndValidity(); <-- Triggers valueChanges!
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks I had to change to `this.userForm.get('password').updateValueAndValidity();this.userForm.get('confirmPassword').updateValueAndValidity();`

Comment: What about if I am using forEach for the formgroup? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63303903/rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-at-abstractcontrol-updatevalueandva

Answer (score 71):

If you want to subscribe to any form changes and still run patchValue inside it, then you could add the `{emitEvent: false}` option to patchValue, thus the patching will not trigger another change detection

code:

```
this.formGroup
    .valueChanges
    .subscribe( _ => {
        this.formGroup.get( 'controlName' ).patchValue( _val, {emitEvent: false} );
    } );
```

PS. This is also less tedious than subscribing to each form control one-by-one to avoid triggering change max call stack exceeded. Especially if you form has 100 controls to subscribe to.

Now to elaborate further, if you still need to updateValueAndValidity inside the subscription, then I suggest you use the `distinctUntilChanged` rxjs operator, to only run the subscription, when some value changes.

distinctUntilChanged documentation can be found here

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html

> **distinctUntilChanged** - Only emit when the current value is different
>   than the last.

Now we will also have to make it a custom validation function, because by default, distinctUntilChanged validates objects by pointer and the pointer is new on every change.

```
this.formGroup
    .valueChanges
    .distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b))
    .subscribe( _ => {
        this.formGroup.get( 'controlName' ).patchValue( _val, {emitEvent: false} );
        this.formGroup.get( 'controlName' ).updateValueAndValidity();
    } );
```

And voila, we are patching and updating, without running into the maximum call stack!

Comment: The solution I was looking for. Bettern than having a boolean 'valueChangesRunning'. +1

Answer (score 48):

My answer is just development of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47821902/9338572).

By adding `distinctUntilChanged()` in the pipeline just before `subscribe()` you avoid the "Maximum call stack size exceeded" because

> **distinctUntilChanged** method only emit when the current value is different than the last.

The usage:

```
this.userForm.get('password')
  .valueChanges.pipe(distinctUntilChanged())         
  .subscribe(val => {})
```

[Documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged)

Comment: What about if I am using forEach for the formgroup? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63303903/rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-at-abstractcontrol-updatevalueandva

Comment: I tried to subscribe to valueChanges of form. At the task needs been to check one checkbox and disable other and vice versa. I get maximum callstack exceeded.```distinctUntilChanged ``` save my time! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 23):

Try adding `distinctUntilChanged()` in the pipeline just before `subscribe()`. It should filter out those "change" events where value was not actually changed.

Comment: This is universal solution, which works also in the case when you perform `valueChanges` on multiple and dependent on each others `formControls`. Thanks!

Comment: Somehow doesn't help me :(

Comment: It just means that your code is different in some way. Post your own question and someone will answer it.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was when I was trying to update the value and validity of a Form Control, it is indeed fixed by the `{ emitEvent: false }` addition:

```
    // making sure that at least one name is filled in
    this.form.get('firstName').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      if (value) {
        this.form.get('lastName').setValidators(Validators.nullValidator);
      } else {
        this.form.get('lastName').setValidators(Validators.required);
      }
      this.form.get('lastName').updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: false }); // <- here
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar error when doing validation. Error raised when call  updateValueAndValidity().in my case I used this overload updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent : false})

try with this

**this.userForm.get('loginTypeId').updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent : false});**

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved hours of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.userForm.get('loginTypeId').enable({emitEvent: false});
```

if you need to enable one select of all selects your form

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link will resolver this and other cases

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11205