# Ionic 5/Angular: Laggy <ion-input> with "Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event" warning on iOS only

Tags: angular8, capacitor, ionic5

I've started getting non-passive event listener warning on a form used in an ionic project. I've reproduced it using a bare-bones ionic tabs project and have the following versions of ionic, angular and capacitor installed:

**Ionic:**
   Ionic CLI                     : 6.4.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli).
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.7.
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.26.
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.26.
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.26.
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0.

**Capacitor:**

Capacitor CLI   : 2.0.1.
   @capacitor/core : 2.0.1.

In Google Chrome, this only appears when I set the device to 'iOS'. There is a noticeable lag between tapping on an ion-input field and the field being available to enter data. This persists when I compile the code and package it as a iOS app. Setting the device as an android device in Google Chrome and compiling as an Android app is unaffected.

To reproduce this issue, create a new ionic tabs app and replace the tab1 files with the following:

**tab1.module.ts**

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Tab1Page } from './tab1.page';
import { ExploreContainerComponentModule } from '../explore-container/explore-container.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ExploreContainerComponentModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab1Page }])
  ],
  declarations: [Tab1Page]
})
export class Tab1PageModule {}
```

**tab1.page.html**

```
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      Calculate Score
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="/tabs/tab2"></ion-back-button>
  </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>  
  <form [formGroup]="batsForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" novalidate>
        <!-- Inputs with labels -->
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="fixed">Age </ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="age" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="Enter age"></ion-input>
        <ion-select formControlName="period" value="years" okText="Select" cancelText="Cancel">
          <ion-select-option value="years">Years</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="months">Months</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
        <!-- <ion-input (click)="showPicker()" value="{{ age }} {{ period }}"></ion-input> -->
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item *ngIf="batsForm.get('age').dirty && errorControl.age.invalid">
        <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="batsForm.get('age').dirty && errorControl.age.errors?.min">
          Age must be greater than 0
        </ion-text>
        <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="batsForm.get('age').dirty && errorControl.age.errors?.max">
          Age must be less than 116
        </ion-text>
        <ion-text color="danger"*ngIf="batsForm.get('age').dirty && errorControl.age.errors?.required">
          An age value is required
        </ion-text>
      </ion-item>


      <ion-radio-group formControlName="penetrating" >
        <ion-list-header>
          <ion-label>Penetrating injury</ion-label>
        </ion-list-header>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" value="yes"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>No</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" value="no" checked></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-radio-group>

      <ion-radio-group formControlName="velocity" >
        <ion-list-header>
          <ion-label>High velocity trauma</ion-label>
        </ion-list-header>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" value="yes"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>No</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" value="no" checked></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-radio-group>


    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="fixed">Systolic BP</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="bp" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*"  min="0" max="240" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="batsForm.get('bp').dirty && errorControl.bp.invalid">
      <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="batsForm.get('bp').dirty && errorControl.bp.errors?.min">
        BP must be greater than 0mmHg
      </ion-text>
      <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="batsForm.get('bp').dirty  && errorControl.bp.errors?.max">
        BP must be less than 240mmHg
      </ion-text>
      <ion-text color="danger"*ngIf="batsForm.get('bp').dirty && errorControl.bp.errors?.required">
        Blood pressure value is required
      </ion-text>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="fixed">GCS</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="gcs" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="3" max="15" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="batsForm.get('gcs').dirty && errorControl.gcs.invalid">
      <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="batsForm.get('gcs').dirty && errorControl.gcs.errors?.min">
        GCS must be 3 or more
      </ion-text>
      <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="batsForm.get('gcs').dirty  && errorControl.gcs.errors?.max">
        GCS must be 15 or less
      </ion-text>
      <ion-text color="danger"*ngIf="batsForm.get('gcs').dirty && errorControl.gcs.errors?.required">
        A GCS is required
      </ion-text>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="fixed">Resp Rate</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="rr" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="60" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="batsForm.get('rr').dirty && errorControl.rr.invalid">
      <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="batsForm.get('rr').dirty && errorControl.rr.errors?.min">
        Resp rate must be greater than 0
      </ion-text>
      <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="batsForm.get('rr').dirty  && errorControl.rr.errors?.max">
        Resp rate must be less than 60
      </ion-text>
      <ion-text color="danger"*ngIf="batsForm.get('rr').dirty && errorControl.rr.errors?.required">
        A respiratory rate is required
      </ion-text>
    </ion-item>


    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="fixed">SpO2 on air</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="spo2" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="50" max="100" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="batsForm.get('spo2').dirty && errorControl.spo2.invalid">
      <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="batsForm.get('spo2').dirty && errorControl.spo2.errors?.min">
        SpO2 be greater than 50%
      </ion-text>
      <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="batsForm.get('spo2').dirty  && errorControl.spo2.errors?.max">
        SpO2 must be 100% or less
      </ion-text>
      <ion-text color="danger"*ngIf="batsForm.get('spo2').dirty && errorControl.spo2.errors?.required">
        SpO2 is required when a respiratory rate is not provided
      </ion-text>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="fixed">Heart Rate </ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="hr" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="180" id="hr" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="batsForm.get('hr').dirty && errorControl.hr.invalid">
      <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="batsForm.get('hr').dirty && errorControl.hr.errors?.min">
        Heart rate must be greater than 0
      </ion-text>
      <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="batsForm.get('hr').dirty && errorControl.hr.errors?.max">
        Heart rate must be less than 180
      </ion-text>
      <ion-text color="danger"*ngIf="batsForm.get('hr').dirty && errorControl.hr.errors?.required">
        Heart rate value is required
      </ion-text>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="fixed">Callsign</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="callsign" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" required placeholder="Enter vehicle callsign"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="batsForm.get('callsign').dirty && errorControl.callsign.invalid">
      <ion-text color="danger"*ngIf="batsForm.get('callsign').dirty && errorControl.callsign.errors?.required">
        Your vehicle callsign is required
      </ion-text>
    </ion-item>

    <div class="ion-padding">
      <ion-button  expand="full" type="submit" class="ion-no-margin" [disabled]="!batsForm.valid" >Calculate Score</ion-button>
    </div>
  </form>

</ion-content>
```

**tab1.page.ts**

```
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { NetworkStatus } from '@capacitor/core';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

const { Network } = Plugins;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})


export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {

  status: NetworkStatus;
  batsForm: FormGroup;

  thenumbers = new Array(100);

  public show = true;
  public spinner = false;
  public loading = null;
  public isSubmitted = false;
  public startGCS = 15;
  public nextID = 1;
  public age: any;
  public period: any;

  constructor(
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.batsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      bp : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(240)]],
      gcs : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(3), Validators.max(15)]],
      rr : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(60)]],
      spo2 : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(50), Validators.max(100)]],
      hr : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(180)]],
      age : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(115)]],
      period : ['', [Validators.required]],
      penetrating : ['', [Validators.required]],
      velocity : ['', [Validators.required]],
      callsign : ['', [Validators.required]]
    });

    this.batsForm.controls.period.setValue('years');

    this.formControlValueChanged();
  }

ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.getStatus();
    this.nextID = 1;
  }

  async getStatus() {
    try {
      this.status = await Network.getStatus();
      console.log(this.status);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error', e);
    }
  }



  get errorControl() {
    return this.batsForm.controls;
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
  // https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/infragistics/posts/how-to-do-conditional-validation-on-valuechanges-method-in-angular-reactive-forms-

  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821809/rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-when-using-valuechanges-subscribe
  formControlValueChanged() {
    const spo2Control = this.batsForm.get('spo2');
    const rrControl = this.batsForm.get('rr');
    this.batsForm.get('rr').valueChanges.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(
        (rr: number) => {
            console.log(rr);
            if ( rr !== null && ( rr > 0 || rr < 50 )) {
                spo2Control.setValidators([Validators.min(50), Validators.max(100)]);
            } else  {
                spo2Control.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.min(50), Validators.max(100)]);

            }
            spo2Control.updateValueAndValidity();
        });
    this.batsForm.get('spo2').valueChanges.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(
        (spo2: number) => {
            console.log(spo2);
            if (spo2 !== null && ( spo2 > 50 || spo2 < 101 )) {
                rrControl.setValidators([Validators.min(0), Validators.max(60)]);
            } else  {
                rrControl.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(60)]);

            }
            rrControl.updateValueAndValidity();
        });

  }

  submitForm() {
      console.log('Form submitted');
      console.log(this.batsForm.value);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else has this issue, reverting to @ionic/angular 5.0.5 fixes the lag issue, although not the passive listener version warning.

Comment: I submitted a bug report on GitHub and it looks like the ionic team are already aware of the [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/21023) and will fix in a future release.